# Somone know why I get the error: ParserError: Expected

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain

**Someone Know why I get the next error:**
ParserError: Expected '{' but got identifier
--> bep-20.sol:5:15:
|
5 | contract Game Changer is ERC20 {
| ^^^^^^^

**this is my code**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Game Changer is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20 ("Game Changer", "GC"){
        _mint(msg.sender,initialSupply);
    }
}
```

thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The contract name should have no spaces:

```
contract GameChanger is ERC20 {
```